# How to extract numbers with leading zeros from mixed Excel cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need extract numbers with leading zeros from mixed cells?

Example cell A1 content:

```
A1: 0012 SomeText
```

I need in cell B1 only numbers with leading zeros:

```
B1: 0012
```

If I put formula `=TEXT(LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1));"@")` in cell formatted as General I get only numbers without leading zeros `12`.

If I put formula in cell formatted as Text formula doesn't work, it shows formula text.

Comment: Will there always be four digits?  If so, replace `"@"` with `"0000"` or just use `=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)`

Comment: `TEXT()` converts a number to a string so strips leading zeros unless you use a format that has them and even then it might not have the number of leading zeros you want. Use string handling functions instead.

Comment: There are various number of numeric characters from 0 to 000001

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your text is `####[space]xxxx`, you can pull the numbers with `LEFT()` and `SEARCH()`:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1;SEARCH(" ";A1)-1))
```

Comment: Since it is a space, FIND will work also.  It is the TEXT that is the problem.

Comment: What does TRIM exactly do in this case?

Comment: @VBasic2008 nothing really, I just have a habit of using that when I'm trying to get specific parts of a string.  In this case I believe the `-1` effectively removed the trailing space.

Comment: Nice. I do this all the time with VBA Split. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: @VBasic2008 no bother at all!

Answer (score 1):

### OP's Approach

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1));REPT("0";FIND(" ";A1)-2)&"#")
```

### Comma Version

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)),REPT("0",FIND(" ",A1)-2)&"#")
```

The previous versions raise the question where the trailing space got lost.

### VBA Version

```
Function LZERO(ZeroString As String) As String
    LZERO = Split(ZeroString)(0)
End Function
```

e.g. `=LZERO(A1)`